# Run current Process in background C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, process, background-process

I have a C# VS2017 Console App. I'd like the CMD prompt to return immediately after executing while the App runs in the background (it's a long running process).
Currently I'm starting the App as a Process from another executable just to do this by setting `Process.StartInfo` properties.
Is there an opposite to `Process.WaitForExit()` that can be set at the start of a program?

I read somewhere using a WinForms App without the form might work, yet I tried to delete the form and sleep for 10 seconds, showing a `MessageBox` after (in `Main`). The program returned and showed the box immediately without sleeping.

Comment: Sounds like you want a Windows Service.

Comment: You want a service like Joel mentioned, that will run in the background.  Otherwise, you would be doing a new thread, that simply runs in the background.

Comment: Cmd.exe checks for the type of program.  And if it is console mode app then it always waits until it completes.  Very important, two programs trying to use the console at the same time never comes to a good end.  So if it needs to not wait then you have to change the Output type with Project > Properties > Application.  And you have to pinvoke AllocConsole() so you get your own console.  Crystal ball says that you slept for 10 milliseconds instead of 10 seconds.

Comment: You can do it with a winform app but it really would depend on what you're trying to do as to how good an idea that is - mostly its not.

Comment: You are right thanks, I'm looking to do a Service and I did mistakenly sleep for 10 milliseconds!